# Question regarding microtype package

Tags: pdftex, packages, warnings, microtype

I am using the *inofficial* thesis template from my university.

However, when I compile I get several warnings in the manner of

`` Package microtype Warning: tracking amount list `output.tex/85' will override list `output.tex/724' for font `T1///sc/' on input line 85. ``

I have no idea what that means. The corresponding lines for the package microtype in the .cls file are :

```
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

% this is necessary so that smallcapped italics & bolds also get spaced
\DeclareMicrotypeSet{ultsmallcaps}
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2},
     shape    = {sc,si,scit}
   }
\microtypesetup{tracking=ultsmallcaps}

% the default tracking is kind of huge, this sets tracking to 5.5% of an em
\SetTracking{encoding = *, shape = {sc,si,scit}}{55}

% Fix bug where ligatures are enabled for smallcaps in noto font
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = {T1}, family = {NotoSans-TOsF}, shape = {sc,si,scit}}

\newif\ifult@microtypeloaded
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{microtype}%
  {%
    \global\ult@microtypeloadedtrue
  }%
  {%
    \global\ult@microtypeloadedfalse
    \global\newif\ifMT@protrusion
    \global\MT@protrusionfalse
  }%
}
```

Can someone explain what that means and if I should care about it?

Comment: `the default tracking is kind of huge, this sets tracking to 5.5% ` says you are changing tracking and ` Package microtype Warning: tracking amount list `output.tex/85' will override ...` is warning that the tracking has changed. I didn't check all the details (that seem vastly over complicated for a thesis setup:-)

Comment: Do you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or XeLaTeX to compile your document?

Comment: @Mico I use pdfLaTeX

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so it basically just tells me that it is doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: as far as I can tell, but your code is pretty weird,  You can't be using all of that stuff, `EU1` and `EU2` encodings have not been used by fontspec (which uses `TU`)  since about 2015 I think. If the class has package has `\usepackage[..]{microtype]` why a few lines later does it have `\@ifpackageloaded{microtype}%`   and whatever `\global\newif\ifMT@protrusion` does it does not do what its author hoped. (it globally sets `\count255` to 92)